# adding .css file to ejs

Tags: css, node.js, express, ejs

im working on node.js(express) with ejs and im not able to include a .css file to it.i tried the same thing seperately as a html-css duo and it worked fine...how can i include the same in  my .ejs file. My app.js goes thus:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');


app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.render('index.ejs', {
        title: 'My Site',
    nav: ['Home','About','Contact'] 
  });
});

app.get('/home', function(req, res){
  res.render('index.ejs', {
        title: 'My Site',
    nav: ['Home','About','Contact'] 
  });
});

app.get('/about', function(req, res){
  res.render('about.ejs', {
    title: 'About',
     nav: ['Home','About','Contact']
  });
});

app.get('/contact', function(req, res){
  res.render('contact.ejs', {
    title: 'Contact',
     nav: ['Home','About','Contact']
  });
});


app.listen(3000);
```

and the index.ejs file:

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</head>
<body>
<div>
    <h1> <%= title %> </h1>
    <ul>
<% for (var i=0; i<nav.length;i++) {%>

<li><a href="/<%=nav[i]%>"> <%=nav[i]%> </a></li>
   &nbsp;  
<% } %>
   </ul>
</div>

<br>
<h3>Node.js</h3>
<p class='just'>Express is agnostic as to which templating language you use. Templating languages can be a hot topic of debate.Here Iam going to use Jade.</p>
<p class ='just'>Again Express is agnostic to what you use to generate your CSS-you can use vanilla CSS but for this example I'm using Stylus.
</p>
<footer>
Running on node with express and ejs
</footer>
</home>
</html>
```

style.css file:

```
<style type="text/css">
body { background-color: #D8D8D8;color: #444;}
h1 {font-weight: bold;text-align: center;}
header { padding: 50px 10px; color: #fff; font-size :15px; text-align:right;}
 p { margin-bottom :20px;  margin-left: 20px;}
 footer {text-decoration: overline; margin-top: 300px}
 div { width:100%; background:#99CC00;position:static; top:0;left:0;}
 .just
 {
    text-align: center; 

 }
a:link {color:#FF0000;}    /* unvisited link */
a:visited {color:#0B614B;} /* visited link */
a:hover {color:#B4045F;}   /* mouse over link */
a:active {color:#0000FF;}

  ul { list-style-type:none; margin:0; padding:0;text-align: right; }
li { display:inline; }
</style>
```

Comment: You shouldn't use the style tags in your css file and you might need to create routes with express that serve your css and other assets.

Answer (score 182, accepted):

Your problem is not actually specific to ejs.

2 things to note here

1. **style.css** is an external css file. So you dont need style tags inside that file. It should only contain the css.
2. In your express app, you have to mention the public directory from which you are serving the static files. Like css/js/image

it can be done by

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

assuming you put the css files in public folder from in your app root.
now you have to refer to the css files in your tamplate files,
like

```
<link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Here i assume you have put the css file in css folder inside your public folder.

So folder structure would be

```
.
./app.js
./public
    /css
        /style.css
```

Answer (score 17):

In order to serve up a static CSS file in express app (i.e. use a css style file to style ejs "templates" files in express app).  Here are the simple 3 steps that need to happen:

1. Place your css file called "styles.css" in a folder called "assets" and the assets folder in a folder called "public".  Thus the relative path to the css file should be "/public/assets/styles.css"
2. In the head of each of your ejs files you would simply call the css file (like you do in a regular html file) with a `<link href=… />` as shown in the code below.  Make sure you copy and paste the code below directly into your ejs file `<head>` section

   ```
   <link href= "/public/assets/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
   ```
3. In your server.js file, you need to use the `app.use()` middleware.  Note that a middleware is nothing but a term that refers to those operations or code that is run between the request and the response operations.  By putting a method in middleware, that method will automatically be called **everytime** between the request and response methods.  To serve up static files (such as a css file) in the `app.use()` middleware there is already a function/method provided by express called `express.static()`.  Lastly, you also need to specify a request route that the program will respond to and serve up the files from the static folder **everytime** the middleware is called. Since you will be placing the css files in your public folder.  In the server.js file, make sure you have the following code:

   ```
   // using app.use to serve up static CSS files in public/assets/ folder when /public link is called in ejs files
   // app.use("/route", express.static("foldername"));
   app.use('/public', express.static('public'));
   ```

After following these simple 3 steps, every time you `res.render('ejsfile')` in your `app.get()` methods you will automatically see the css styling being called.  You can test by accessing your routes in the browser.

Answer (score 14):

You can use this

```
     var fs = require('fs');
     var myCss = {
         style : fs.readFileSync('./style.css','utf8');
     };

     app.get('/', function(req, res){
       res.render('index.ejs', {
       title: 'My Site',
       myCss: myCss
      });
     });
```

put this on template

```
   <%- myCss.style %>
```

just build style.css

```
  <style>
    body { 
     background-color: #D8D8D8;
     color: #444;
   }
  </style>
```

I try this for some custom css. It works for me

Answer (score 5):

As I see you are using EJS with express.js

- Firstly, there is a better way to add EJS

  ```
   app.set("view engine", "ejs");
  ```

  and for that, your file structure should be like

  ```
   .
   ./app.js
   ./view
       /index.ejs
  ```
- And for adding CSS to your EJS file, you have to use "public" folder (or any other name, name doesn't matter) from which you can serve static file like CSS, JS or images

  For accessing that, you can use

  ```
   app.use(express.static("public"));  //better and newer way than first answer
  ```

  and is your EJS file, you can link your CSS by

  ```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  ```

  Here I am assuming that, you put your CSS file in your CSS folder inside public folder

  So, your file structure will be like

  ```
   .
   ./app.js
   ./public
       /css
           /style.css
   ./view
       /index.ejs
  ```

Answer (score 3):

I tried a different approach. I created an ejs file for my styles called ***styles.ejs*** and added all the css inside the tags like this.

```
<style>
    body {
      font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    }

    #container {
      margin: 0 10%;
      padding: 20px;
      border: 10px solid #c8102e;
    }
</style>
```

and I have includes this file inside *head* tag of my index.ejs like this.

```
<head>
   <%- include('./css/styles'); %>
</head>
```

It worked well for me.

Answer (score -2):

Add below code to serve static files

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

create a folder named public in your root folder and add your styles files inside public folder.and change your linking css code as below.

```
<link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

So folder structure should be:

```
.
./app.js
./public
   /style.css
```

Comment: Why are you mixing HTML with your JavaScript? You should clarify that those two lines of code should be in different files.