# How can I join my css and js to the node project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, localhost

https://github.com/Alesha24/restaurants/blob/master/restplatzproject.zip

There is a small node project at the link above. It can be started with `node app.js` command and later opening http://localhost:8000/.

However it does not render index.handelbars file inside the views folder. Neither styles, nor .js files are being uploaded. To do so I added

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/js')));
```

to my express server but it didn't help either. What am I doing wrong?

```
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const ejs = require('ejs');
const paypal = require('paypal-rest-sdk');






const exphbs  = require('express-handlebars');
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/js')));

// app.use(express.static('js'));

app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({defaultLayhhout: 'main'}));
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
// app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.get('/', (req, res) => res.render('index'));

app.post('/pay', (req, res) => {
  const create_payment_json = {
    "intent": "sale",
    "payer": {
        "payment_method": "paypal"
    },
    "redirect_urls": {
        "return_url": "http://localhost:8000/success",
        "cancel_url": "http://localhost:8000/cancel"
    },
    "transactions": [{
        "item_list": {
            "items": [{
                "name": "Red Sox Hat",
                "sku": "001",
                "price": "25.00",
                "currency": "USD",
                "quantity": 1
            }]
        },
        "amount": {
            "currency": "USD",
            "total": "25.00"
        },
        "description": "Hat for the best team ever"
    }]
};

paypal.payment.create(create_payment_json, function (error, payment) {
  if (error) {
      throw error;
  } else {
      for(let i = 0;i < payment.links.length;i++){
        if(payment.links[i].rel === 'approval_url'){
          res.redirect(payment.links[i].href);
        }
      }
  }
});

});

app.get('/success', (req, res) => {
  const payerId = req.query.PayerID;
  const paymentId = req.query.paymentId;

  const execute_payment_json = {
    "payer_id": payerId,
    "transactions": [{
        "amount": {
            "currency": "USD",
            "total": "25.00"
        }
    }]
  };

  paypal.payment.execute(paymentId, execute_payment_json, function (error, payment) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error.response);
        throw error;
    } else {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(payment));
        res.send('Success');
    }
});
});

app.get('/cancel', (req, res) => res.send('Cancelled'));

app.listen(8000, () => console.log('Server Started'));
```

Comment: Why would you use your `/js` directory as your root path?  Show your actual code here in your question.

Comment: @Brad just updated the question

Comment: I really hope for your sake that isnt a real paypal id/secret...

Comment: @LukeMcGregor surely not. It's sandbox :) Do you know how to help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I include css files using node, express, and ejs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24582338/how-can-i-include-css-files-using-node-express-and-ejs)