# Express static directory not working with CSS path

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have this in my app.js

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../public')));
```

..and this is my main layout page

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css">
```

I've tried just about every combination I can think of, but I can't get the stylesheet to connect.

You can view the repo here to understand the file hierarchy - https://github.com/NolWag/Shopify-eCommerce-App

[image]

I can't seem to figure out what I'm missing, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your repo says [`app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../public')));`](https://github.com/NolWag/Shopify-eCommerce-App/blob/master/app.js#L27), not `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));`.

Comment: Mistype on my part, either case doesn't work.

Comment: You might get more consistent results with `app.use(express.static(path.join(process.cwd(), '/public')));`, though maybe not. It appears your css may not be getting loaded at all based on [this](https://github.com/NolWag/Shopify-eCommerce-App/blob/master/dist/bundle.js#L765).

Comment: I'd first determine whether and where the css is getting served.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts that did the trick! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Please use
`app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, './public')));`
instead of
`app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../public')));`

Of course, there are some problems in serve static files
[How can I include css files using node, express, and ejs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24582338)
But, from your project, there is no problem

---

**Interesting story: WHY We cannot find `../public` is wrong path.**

[image: Screen]

With chrome inspect, we can think as there are some mime type error.

---

???: 
Although there is no files for `express.static`, express is send message as

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Error</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <pre>Cannot GET /css/styles.css</pre>
    </body>
</html>
```

instead of **404**.

---

=>
So, we are confused, and We cannot detect there is no the `styles.css`.

---

We can debug with `http://localhost:3000/css/styles.css`, then we can find `Cannot GET /css/styles.css`.
So, we can find `../public` is wrong, and fixed with `./public`.