# HTML does not load CSS due to wrong path

Tags: html, css, node.js, express

I have  an application which serves html and looks like this.

```
// ... 
var staticPath = config.development.staticFiles;
app.get('/category/:catName', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, staticPath + "shop-grid.html"));
})

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, staticPath + "index.html"));
})  
// ...
```

In each html, the css are linked like this .

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
```

The **index.html** works fine, but the **"shop-grid.html"** does not load with css, because it tried to load css at "localhost:8080/**category**/css/style.css" instead of "localhost:8080/css/style.css", which works for the first html.

What did i do wrong here ?

Comment: Maybe this will answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24582622/5833816

Comment: @LazarNikolic like i said, the same thing works for "index.html", i guess using the different path ("/category" instead of "/")  also changes the path which html loads css ?

The link you posted didnt help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What bothers me is why was the relative path changed ? The htmls are in the same directory, only the url is changed.

The browser knows nothing about how you have stored files on the server.

It **only** knows about URLs.

`css/style.css` is a **relative** path.

Relative paths are resolved by taking the URL of the current page, removing everything after the last `/` in the path, then appending the relative path.

`http://localhost:8080/` + `css/style.css` = `http://localhost:8080/css/style.css`

`http://localhost:8080/category/cats` + `css/style.css` = `http://localhost:8080/category/css/style.css`

---

Use an **absolute** path: `/css/style.css`.

Absolute paths are resolved by removing the entire path (i.e. everything after the hostname and (if present) port number) and then appending the absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

You are redirecting both cases and therefore chaning your _dirname. but when you load the shop-grid.html, you are redirecting to another directory entirely. the href path isnt global its a relative path.

Comment: What bothers me is why was the relative path changed ? The htmls are in the same directory, only the url is changed.

Comment: The path is relative to your current path
`/category`
becomes your new root path, since you are redirecting towards it.