# Css not loading on node.js generated link

Tags: css, node.js

I'm using node.js, express and mysql.
I have successfully followed these instructions to include my css file:
[How can I include css files using node, express, and ejs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24582338/how-can-i-include-css-files-using-node-express-and-ejs)
The css does load on every page, except one link that contains an id in the url:

```
http://localhost:8089/edit/123
```

The last number is passed from the previous page, when the user clicks on an 'edit' link in a table row.
The styling is not loading on this edit page. It does load everywhere else.
My node.js server file:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

The edit.html is in the same 'views' folder as the other pages. The css link is the same in the html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
```

Can someone help what the problem is and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add /

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
```

this way it will return to the document root not on here /edit/123/css/style.css

Comment: Ohh well, that was easy. :D Thank you!