# express.js public folder not being recognised

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, express, file

I have developed a simple server in Node.js using Express and I have set the `public` folder to serve static files.

In my root `index.js`, I have the following code:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http').Server(app);
const fs = require('fs');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/', (req, res) =>  {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html'); 
});

http.listen(3000, () => console.log('started server on *:3000'));
```

And the directory structure is:

```
root 
|---index.js
|---package.json
|---public
|   |---index.html
|   |---cs
|   |   |---index.css
|   |---js
|   |   |---index.js
```

In the `index.html` in the `public` folder, I have the following code:

```
<head>
    <script src="js/index.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" src="css/index.css" type="text/css" >
</head>
```

But no CSS is being rendered. How can I resolve this?

Comment: i think the `link` tags have `href` attributes instead of `src`

Comment: there is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24582622/11062213) i think it could help you

Comment: @SudhirBastakoti changing to `href` worked, but some answers here suggests changing to `src`... but thanks a lot..

Comment: Perhaps it's a typo, but when editing your question, I noticed that you have a `cs` folder instead of a `css` folder in your directory structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `src` attribute in `link` tag to `href`. If this doesn't work then try below solution.

I'm considering your server is running on `http://localhost:3000/`

So update the url in `src` of your `index.html` in public folder by appending with the base url as I did below.

```
<head>
    <script src="http://localhost:3000/js/index.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost:3000/css/index.css" type="text/css" >
</head>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

To this:

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
```