# Trying to move JS from HTML file to it's own file

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, handlebars.js

I have a bunch of javascript between `<script>` tags in an html file and I'm trying to move it to it's own file to make it a little more organized.

I pasted the javascript like so into a file called dashboard.js located in the same folder as the html(.hbs) file:

```
$('#bidButton').on('click', function(e) {
  var bidAmount = $("#bidAmount").val() * 100;
  var bidAmount2 = $("#bidAmount").val();
  var bidDisplayAmount = parseFloat(Math.floor($("#bidAmount").val() * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
  var credits = $("#credits").val();
  var bidPlusFive = $("#bidPlusFive").val();
  if (parseFloat(credits) < 0) {
    $(".success-messages").fadeOut();
    return $(".error-messages").text("Please add funds to your account before bidding.").fadeIn();
  } else if (bidAmount < bidPlusFive * 100) {
    $(".success-messages").fadeOut();
    return $(".error-messages").text("Must bid $" + bidPlusFive + " or more!").fadeIn();
  } else if (!isNaN(bidAmount)) {
    $(".error-messages").fadeOut();
    $.post("/bid/bid", {
        bidAmount: bidAmount2
      },
      function(data, status) {
        $(".error-messages").fadeOut();
        $(".success-messages").text("Congratulations! You're the highest bidder!").fadeIn();
        $("#currentBid").hide();
        $("#currentBid2").show();
        $("#currentBid3").text(bidAmount2).show();
        $("#newBidPlusFive").hide();
        $("#newBidPlusFive2").show();
        $("#newBidPlusFive3").text(parseFloat(bidAmount2) + 5).show();
      });
  } else {
    return $(".error-messages").text("Invalid amount").fadeIn();
  }

});
```

I then put this line of code in the html file:

```
<script src="dashboard.js"></script>
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Also, when I load the page in the browser, I'm getting a console error of: `SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'`. So, for some reason, my hbs layout template is getting rendered in the js file instead of the js.

Comment: Removed the image, replaced with code

Comment: "So, for some reason, my hbs layout template is getting rendered in the js file instead of the js" — That's down to the server configuration and not the contents of the JS file.

Comment: @Quentin Any idea where to fix this?

Comment: Maybe this line causes error: `parseFloat(Math.floor($("#bidAmount").val() * 100) / 100).toFixed(2); ` . Which type is of bidAmount?

Comment: Are you using express on top of node?

Comment: @HTCom, it all worked perfectly when it what in the .hbs file so I don't think anything is wrong with the javascript.

Comment: @Brian yes, using express

Comment: Dupe? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39912609/how-to-include-static-files-in-express-js

Comment: what @Quentin said. You're using hbs for your view engine, which means it doesn't matter where your views are stored. Your javascript file should be in the root of the static directory based on your script tag

Comment: `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));` This is in my app.js file so I moved the javascript file to /public/javascripts/. Is that what you mean?

Comment: in that case change your script tag to `<script src="/javascripts/dashboard.js"></script>`